# Braking system for a miniature ‘Drop tower’ rollercoaster

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, design, electromagnetism

The tower itself is only max 400mm.
Designing the lifting system isn’t the problem but slowing down the gondola is posing a slight problem, any suggestions?

I have looked into using magnets but I can’t wrap my head around how they work.

Comment: How do they work on full-sized versions?

Comment: Magnets are key components in electric motors. What do magnets do there? Force applied over distance is work. Anything that resembles a spring should work.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you must use magnets then its possible to utilize a neat physics trick. See there are materials that are paramagnetic (aluminium, copper etc).  A magnetic field moving through a paramagnetic material will cause current to flow through the material. This in turn will cause  the moving object to break rapidly.

In your particular usecase this has the following advantages.

1. Its extremely simple and requires no moving parts.
2. Provided that you use permanent magnets then the system is very reliable. As there is no contact whatsoever.
3. Its easy to design custom braking force sequences.

To see this effect in action see [this](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=sENgdSF8ppA), [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nV4yA8OYwmE) and [this](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=MglUIiBy2lQ) on youtube.

The other common alternative is to use air breaks. What you so is affix horisontal slats on sides of the dropping objects. then you close off the airflow when you reach near ground causing air to cushion the fall. Simillary to above this is also extremely reliable system. And has most of the same benefits as magnetic breaking, although it is more noisy.

Motor breaking also works but it relies on many more factors. And thus there is more things that can go wrong. Especially since there are maintenance requiring components in the mix.

Answer (score 1):

> Designing the lifting system isn’t the problem but slowing down the gondola is posing a slight problem,

See if you can use the lifting system itself as the braking system.

> I have looked into using magnets but I can’t wrap my head around how they work.

1. Convert the linear motion of the tower to rotary motion (e.g. rack and pinion type arrangement).
2. Connect the rotating part to a generator. (Brushed DC motors with permanent magnets inside will work as generator if rotated by out side force.)
3. Connect the generator output to a resistor. The generator converts the linear movement of the gondola into electrical energy. The resistor connected to the generator dissipates it as heat. Kinetic energy of gondola is dissipated this way by using electricity as intermediary.
4. Tune the resistance to get the required braking effect.

This method has disadvantage that the energy removal rate decreases with decreasing velocity. So it can never bring the gondola to a complete stop. To over come this,

5. Bring the gondola to a complete stop with a shock absorber (or simple spring) at the very end.

By using a DC generator of the required specification, we get around the need to understand how magnets works.