# Any information on magnetic braking with copper?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnets, braking

I have an engineering project where I have to design and build a model of a drop tower from a theme park. The tower itself can be no taller than 40cm.

I plan to use magnetic braking with copper to stop the ride at the bottom. I intend to have the base of the moving seats either made out of magnets or have magnets attached to the side. Then I want to have two copper blocks, maybe 15cm long and 2cm wide/thick, on the inside of the tower itself. The seats would be attached to the front of a block that would move up and down inside the tower. When the seats fall, I would have the copper at the bottom, surrounding the base of the seats and have it slowly descend the last 15cm.

I would appreciate and advice or links on this topic, whether it be how thick the copper needs to be, how strong a magnet would have to be or a link to a paper published on the topic.

I also believe the same effect happens with aluminum, does it work as effectively? Would it be cheaper to make it out of aluminum? I assume I would not be able to construct the rest of the tower out of aluminum as it would hinder the piece falling when I want it to be in freefall.

I believe this falls under Lenz's law but I'm not certain so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: is this also your question? https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56360/braking-system-for-a-miniature-drop-tower-rollercoaster

Comment: Copper will be stronger than aluminum because copper is a better conductor.  [Faraday & Lenz' Law for Aluminum, Carbon, Copper](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gpGpYnrPGcE)

Comment: @jsotola Not my question, possibly someone from the same country as the project is part of the school system.